# jQuery - .on('click', ...) event fires two times in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a search field in which the user enters a letter and the ajax script in the background performs a search. The results are displayed live in a ul-li list. The user can click on the li which class is 'search_list_item'. After the click the username/id is copied into another div (the msg-receiver div).

I have a strange behaviour because in Safari everything works fine. In firefox the click-event seems to be fired two times, because i see the username two times in the #msg_receiver-div.

The code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#searchresult').on('click', 'li.search_list_item', function(){

    var msg_receiver_content = $('#msg_receiver').html();

    $('#msg_receiver').html(msg_receiver_content + ' <li class="single_receiver" id="single_receiver_'+$(this).attr('id')+'">'+$(this).find('span').html()+'</li>');

    $('#single_receiver_'+$(this).attr('id')).hide().fadeIn(500);

    });
});
```

Does anybody know why the code is called two times in FF and one time in Safari - i only click one time on the li in the search result.

Edit:
In the initial state the #msg_receiver-div is empty, but it seems like the statement `$('#msg_receiver').html(` is performed before the variable `msg_receiver_content` has some content and then the variable has the content which should be added afterwards...

Comment: seems weird. can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: Tried to rebuild this, but the event gets fired only once. +1 for fiddle. And you could also use `.append()` instead of fetching the whole content and concat it with another string.

Comment: I try to deliver a fiddle tomorrow. Time is short. I tried it with append and even then i get the content two times.

Even more weird is the fact, that it occurs when opening the page the first time. After i hit reload and the whole page refreshed everything works fine...

Comment: Hello, i found out that the $(document).ready(function(){ is fired twice when adding a console.log('init'); to it. But this happens only, if i open the window the first time! After i reload the page with CMD+R the event is fired once. Why is this happening? I included the .js script only once in the <head> section of the page.

Answer (score 6):

I have been struggling with the same issue. All events seem to work fine, the `click` event however seems to be firing multiple times. Adding the `.off()` before `.on()` seems to solve this issue.

This is causing multiple `click` events:

```
$("#select").on("click", function(event){
    //do something
});
```

This is firing exactly one `click` event. I have not been able to trigger multiple events so far with this:

```
$("#select").off().on("click", function(event){
    //do something
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You might need `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent event bubbling (which is probably happening).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#searchresult').on('click', 'li.search_list_item', function(event){

        event.stopPropagation(); // stop event bubbling

        var msg_receiver_content = $('#msg_receiver').html();

        $('#msg_receiver').html(msg_receiver_content + ' <li class="single_receiver" id="single_receiver_'+$(this).attr('id')+'">'+$(this).find('span').html()+'</li>');

        $('#single_receiver_'+$(this).attr('id')).hide().fadeIn(500);

    });
});
```

Comment: Hello i tried it, but it is not working. I tried it with
var event = jQuery.Event("click"); before the $('#searchresult...

Answer (score 0):

You can set a locking variable, since this action takes time, it should lock out the second click event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var blockClick = false;

    $('#searchresult').on('click', 'li.search_list_item', function(){

    if(blockClick){
    }else{

        blockClick = true;

        var msg_receiver_content = $('#msg_receiver').html();

        $('#msg_receiver').html(msg_receiver_content + ' <li class="single_receiver" id="single_receiver_'+$(this).attr('id')+'">'+$(this).find('span').html()+'</li>');

        $('#single_receiver_'+$(this).attr('id')).hide().fadeIn(500);

        blockClick=false;
    }
    });
});
```