# click() method firing twice on firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, click

I have used the method described here:

http://ericbidelman.tumblr.com/post/14636214755/making-file-inputs-a-pleasure-to-look-at

to programmatically fire a file input box from a button control. It is working well in Chrome and IE but opens the File Upload window twice in Firefox.

The following posts seem similar and I have tried adding stopPropagation to the click event but it made no difference.

[jQuery - .on('click', ...) event fires two times in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366532/jquery-onclick-event-fires-two-times-in-firefox)

[jQuery click event fired twice in firefox but not in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385939/jquery-click-event-fired-twice-in-firefox-but-not-in-ie)

Thanks.

EDIT

The relevant HTML is:

```
<button type="button" id="load_slow_button">Load Playlist</button>
<input id="load_slow_list" type="file" onchange="load_list(this.id)">
```

The relevant Javascript for the button is:

```
document.getElementById("load_slow_button").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    document.getElementById("load_slow_list").click();
    event.stopPropagation;
}, false);
```

The Javascript for the file input is a standard file handler which works fine when the file input is clicked manually.

Comment: show us your code please

Comment: Code has been added...

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by making the event handler a named function.

Within the init() function  which runs when the window loads:

```
document.getElementById("load_fast_button").addEventListener("click", process_click_fast, false);
```

And then the event handler in a separate named function:

```
function process_click_fast() {
    document.getElementById("load_fast_list").click();
}
```

I don't know why this solves the problem so I'd appreciate hearing from anyone who does know!